# MySQL INSERT query returns "You have an error in your SQL syntax" error

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.4, mysql-5.6

I have got following error in a simple PHP page when I tried to insert a row in a table "userstbl"

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'userstbl\' (\'usr_name\', \'usr_pwd\', \'usr_fname\', \'usr_lname\') VALUES (\' at line 1

Here is the code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test_sms"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
$value = "INSERT INTO 'userstbl' ('usr_name', 'usr_pwd', 'usr_fname', 'usr_lname') VALUES ('Aftab','xyz','Aftab','Hussain')";
$sqlin = mysql_prep($value);
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sqlin)){
    die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
$sqlot = "SELECT * FROM 'usertbl'";
$sqlo = mysql_prep($sqlot);
$sqlout = mysqli_query($con , $sqlo);
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlout));
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_pwd'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_fname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_lname'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test_sms"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
$value = "INSERT INTO userstbl (usr_name, usr_pwd, usr_fname, usr_lname) VALUES ('Aftab','xyz','Aftab','Hussain')";
$sqlin = mysql_prep($value);
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sqlin)){
    die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
$sqlot = "SELECT * FROM usertbl";
$sqlo = mysql_prep($sqlot);
$sqlout = mysqli_query($con , $sqlo);
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlout));
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_pwd'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_fname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['usr_lname'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to escape column and table names use backticks, not quotes

```
INSERT INTO `userstbl` (`usr_name`, usr_pwd, usr_fname, usr_lname)
VALUES ('Aftab', 'xyz', 'Aftab', 'Hussain')
```

Comment: The values need quotes if they are strings. But backticks are used to escape names. You always need quotes for strings. But you only need backticks for names if they are like reserved words in MySQL.

Comment: Example: If you have a column named `select` then you have to escape that with backticks